# Deep reduce(): using functions with multiple return values

Tags: python, functional-programming, reduce, hierarchy

I was able to figure how to apply different reduce-funcs at every level of hierarchy in a list-of-lists structure.

```
 def deep_reduce(funs, lol):

     def isi(a): return isinstance(a, (list,tuple,types.GeneratorType))
     def calc(a,b):
         a1 = deep_reduce(funs[1:], a) if isi(a) else a
         b1 = deep_reduce(funs[1:], b) if isi(b) else b
         return funs[0](a1,b1)  

     if isi(lol): return reduce(calc,lol)
     else: return lol



  : import operator as ops

  : cat=lambda a,b: f'{a} x {b}'

  : deep_reduce([cat,ops.sub,ops.add],[[1,2,3],[1,1,3,[1,1]]])
  : '-4 x -5'
```

That's good... now the question is:

How to handle/write functions with multiple return values that will 'accumulate' the same way as single?

`.add` and `.sub` return single value.

Something along the lines work for a single step

```
  : add=lambda a,b: (f'{a}+{b}', a+b )
```

and `if funs=[add,sub,add],` should return:

```
 ( '(1+2+3+(1-1-3-(1+1))', 1 )
```

i.e. simultaneously the string representation and the calculation. The goal is to use single call to `deep_reduce()`. It's the same as calling a loop once and doing different calculations (that return their specific result), rather than N-times for every calculation separately.

Functions like this works the first two steps of the recursion...

```
  add=lambda a,b: (f'{a[0]}+{b[0]}', a[1]+b[1]) if isinstance(a,tuple) else (f'{a}+{b}',a+b)
```

Seems like the functions will also require some sort of reduce!

What would be a faster/simpler implementation?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: At least make it clear - what's the *fun* (or challenge) that you've experienced - so we can get it?

Comment: Will you explain more about what you are actually trying to accomplish? What is the goal? You have shown a lot of code showing **how** you are doing something, but you haven't explained what you are trying to do.

Comment: how to make functions which return multiple values work, f.e. if I have .add() that returns both string representation and the sum .. the expectation is that this will propagate throughout the whole recursion .. . currently it works for single return value.. but not for tuple, cant figure how to construct the function